# Nested cross-validation with Spark_sklearn GridSearchCV results in SPARK-5063 error

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

Performing nested cross validation with Spark_sklearn GridSearchCV as inner cv and sklearn cross_validate/cross_val_score as outer cv results in "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation" error.

```
inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
outer_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
scoring_metric = ['roc_auc', 'average_precision', 'precision']
gs = GridSearchCV(sparkcontext, estimator=RandomForestClassifier(
                                          class_weight='balanced_subsample', n_jobs=-1),
                  param_grid=[{"max_depth": [5], "max_features": [.5, .8], 
                               "min_samples_split": [2], "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 5, 10], 
                               "bootstrap": [True, False], "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"], 
                               "n_estimators": [300]}], 
                  scoring=scoring_metric, cv=inner_cv, verbose=verbose, n_jobs=-1, 
                  refit='roc_auc', return_train_score=False)
scores = cross_validate(gs, X, y, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring_metric, n_jobs=-1, 
                        return_train_score=False)
```

I have tried making `n_jobs=-1` to `n_jobs=1` to remove joblib based parallelism and try again but it still produces the same exception.

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

```
Complete Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_evaluation.py", line 350, in <module>
    main()
  File "model_evaluation.py", line 269, in main
    scores = cross_validate(gs, X, y, cv=outer_cv, scoring=scoring_metric, n_jobs=-1, return_train_score=False)
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 195, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 620, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 195, in <genexpr>
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 61, in clone
    new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
  File "../python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 52, in clone
    return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 279, in __getnewargs__
    "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast 
variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not 
in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

---

edit:
It seems the issue is that sklearn cross_validate() clones the estimator for each fit in a fashion similar to pickling the estimator object which is not allowed for PySpark GridsearchCV estimator because a SparkContext() object cannot/should not be pickled. So how do we correctly clone the estimator?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a solution. The problem occurs when the scikit-learn clone() function tries to deepcopy the SparkContext object. The solution that I used is a bit hacky and I would definitely go another way if there was a better solution but it works. Import the copy class and override the deepcopy() function to simply ignore the SparkContext object if it sees one.

```
# Mock the deep-copy function to ignore copying sparkcontext objects
# Helps avoid pickling error or broadcast variable errors
import copy
_deepcopy = copy.deepcopy

def mock_deepcopy(*args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(args[0], SparkContext):
        return args[0]
    return _deepcopy(*args, **kwargs)

copy.deepcopy = mock_deepcopy
```

So now it will not try to copy the SparkContext object and all seems to work correctly.

Comment: This is cool but I cannot believe I am unable to find a simpler answer. There must be ways to do nested CV with Spark by now?